# How to get a program to run with arrays and methods?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am having an issue with my homework assignment. When the program runs it keeps asking the user to enter the dealers twice instead of once, also when try to calculate to total commission it wrong, and also total sales can't get it to run.

```
Sales
commission
$1 - $5,000
8%
More than $5,000 to $15,000
15%
More than $15,000
20%
```

Problem:

> Write a method to input and return the number of dealers. Perform the appropriate data validation here.
>
> Write a method to gather the required input data. Perform the appropriate data validation here.
>
> Write a method to calculate the commission array.
>
> Write a method to calculate and return total sales for the dealership. Totals sales does not include the commission.
>
> Write a method to calculate and return average sales for the dealership. The average sales value does not include the commission.
>
> Write a method to calculate and return the total commission for the dealership.
>
> Write a method to display the dealer name and amount of sales and the amount of commission for all dealers in a tabular format.
>
> Write a method that accepts the name of a dealer as its parameter and returns the amount of commission for the given dealer. If the given name does not exist, issue an error message.
>
> In your main method, make sure to call your methods to perform the operations. MAKE sure to display all the calculated data returned by your methods. For example, the totals and averages must be displayed, so the answers could be checked. Make output descriptive and provide 2 digits after the decimal point for all monetary values.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int d = dealers();
        
        int [] numberDealers = new int [dealers()];
        String [] employeeInfo = new String[numberDealers.length];
        dealerInfo(employeeInfo.length);
        getCommission(d);
        //dealerTotalSales(employeeInfo.length);    
    }
    
    //Method to get number of dealers from user input
    public static int dealers() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner for user input
        System.out.println("Enter the number of dealears: "); 
        
        int numberDealers = input.nextInt();//Read user input
        //Check to see if user is in range
        //While not in range display error message and ask for input again
        while(numberDealers < 0 || numberDealers > 20) 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid number, Please enter a number dealers 
        from 0 - 20!");
            numberDealers = input.nextInt();
        }
        return numberDealers; //Return number of Dealers
    }
    public static void dealerInfo(int dealer) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner for user input
        String[] dealersName = new String [dealer];
        double[] dealerSales = new double [dealer];
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < dealer; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("\nEnter the name of dealer: ");
            dealersName[i] = input.next();
            
            System.out.println("\nEnter the sales for dealer:  ");
            dealerSales[i] = input.nextDouble();
            
            System.out.println("Name     "  +  "Sales");    
            System.out.println(dealersName[i] + "       " + dealerSales[i]);
        }   
        
        
        
    }
    
    public static void getCommission( int totalSales) {
        double commission = 0.0;
        double commissionRate ;
        if( totalSales >0 && totalSales < 5000) {
            commission = 0.10;
            //System.out.print(commission);
        }else if(totalSales < 15000 ){
            commission = 0.15;
            //System.out.print(commission);

        }else {
            commission = 0.20;  
            //System.out.print(commission);
        
        }
        commissionRate = commission + totalSales;
        System.out.println("\n"+commissionRate );
        
    }
        
        
        
    
    
    public static double dealerTotalSales(int[] numDealers)
    {
        double totalSales = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numDealers.length; i++) {
            totalSales = totalSales + numDealers[i];    
        }
        return totalSales;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int d = dealers(); int [] _ = new int[ dealers() ];`  You call `dealers()` twice ... you get asked for the number of dealers twice.  Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: It's worth understanding how to introduce context before asking questions here. There is a mention of "the dealers" without lettings us know who or what they are (car dealers? card dealers? drug dealers?). Then there is some sales commission information added without any information about its relevance, and then the homework assignment was dumped in without any preamble or formatting. It is probably best to say you have a homework problem, then show the problem itself, then define your terms, then explain the problem you are having, and then show the code, in that order.

Comment: Dealers was used in the method to get there names, commission is there to get the commission from the dealer sale that is entered. The problem I am having is when I run the program is when commission is ran it prints 0.

Answer (score 1):

The reason its asking you to enter the number of dealers two times is because you are calling the dealers() function twice in your main function. you can solve this by replacing

```
int [] numberDealers = new int [dealers()];
```

with

```
int [] numberDealers = new int [d];
```